# Detect keypress in WPF Tooltip

Tags: wpf, user-controls, tooltip

In WPF I wanted to create a custom tooltip that, when open, could detect F1 key press, to take the user to a more detailed help file.

For reusability, my approach is to create a `UserControl` as a tooltip. The control will detect the `KeyDown` event and then execute a bindable `Command`.

But in practice the `KeyDown` event never appears to fire. Maybe Tooltips are not focusable for keyboard events? I have tried setting the `KeyDown` event for the `UserControl`, then for child controls inside the `UserControl`, no luck either way.

Here is (one example) of UserControl with KeyDown event:

```
<UserControl x:Class="HotKeyToolTip"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         KeyDown="UserControl_KeyDown">
```

Here is an example of how this control would be declared as a tooltip, in this case for the items of a combobox:

```
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="Control.ToolTip">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <local:HotKeyToolTip Focusable="True"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Try `PreviewKeyDown` instead and see if that fires the event

Comment: Good idea but `PreviewKeyDown` did not appear to change things. I think the `Combobox` still has the focus in my example - key down on the right letter will switch between selected items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to handle KeyDown in ToolTip/UserControl, because if ToolTip will get focus, the combobox will loose it and so will close the dropdown AND ToolTip. You can take a look upon [How to intercept all the keyboard events and prevent losing focus in a WinForms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579658/how-to-intercept-all-the-keyboard-events-and-prevent-losing-focus-in-a-winforms)

I would handle KeyDown in Combobox and get/set tooltip text. For more flexibility I would implement it as a behavior!

```
        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="Control">
                <Setter Property="Control.ToolTip">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ToolTip>
                            <local:HotKeyToolTip />
                        </ToolTip>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>


private void ComboBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key==Key.F1)
            {
                var cmb = sender as ComboBox;
                var cmbi = cmb.Items.OfType<ComboBoxItem>().ToList();
                if (cmbi != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in cmbi)
                    {
                        var tt = item.ToolTip as ToolTip;
                        if (tt != null && tt.IsOpen && tt.PlacementTarget == item)
                        {
                            (tt.Content as HotKeyToolTip).YourToolTipText = item.Content.ToString();//item.DataContext.ToolTipExtendedText
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: That makes sense, and pretty much what I was doing before I tried to capture `keydown` in the `tooltip`. I went a step further and bound the `ToolTip.IsOpen` to my viewmodel, but even doing that was not a slam dunk.