# Program that listen keyboard events when its minimized? Windoiws Forms C#

Tags: c#, windows, forms, background, minimized

I wanted to ask.Im doing a program that when its minimized or some other window are opened to read my keys and if "specific" is pressed to do something. I used InputSimulator but its working only when a program is in normal window state.if program are minimized. didnt responde?What should i use to make it working in background ?

Comment: You would probably need to do this low level, with calls into the Windows API.  Key presses aren't passed into your application's message queue if the kernel thinks it shouldn't (like it doesn't have any focus).

Comment: Minimized programs do lose focus, other approaches would require windows API (@Zer0's comment) or creating a driver (not recommended in c#, kinda lack of information imho)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to intercept all the keyboard events and prevent losing focus in a WinForms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579658/how-to-intercept-all-the-keyboard-events-and-prevent-losing-focus-in-a-winforms)

Answer (score 2):

You should use [RegisterHotKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey) API functions to regist hotkeys for your processes, also [here](https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/180436-global-hotkeys/) is an example for it.