# C# Form, key input while in the background

Tags: c#, forms, input

atm i try to make a C# Form register key inputs while being in the background. With the help of the internet i got some Code working as intended, the only issue is that i cant figure out how to change my key to a non ModifiyerKey ( like A,B,C..). Maybe someone can give me a hint how to do it, thank you in advance for your taking your time!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Threading;

namespace Performance_Monitor
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        bool isRunning = true;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TopMost = true;
            Thread TH = new Thread(Key_inputs);
            TH.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
            TH.Start();
        }
        void Key_inputs()
        {
            while (isRunning)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100); //reduce cpu load

                if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) != 0) //here is the Key i try change
                {
                    pictureBox1.Show();
                    pictureBox2.Hide();

                    pictureBox1.Location = new Point(1400, 500);

                    label1.Text = pictureBox1.Location.X.ToString();

                }

            }

        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            isRunning = false;
        }

 

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot have a background 'key handler' to intercept all keyboard events. Your application must be active and in the foreground to receive keyboard events.

Comment: do you know it there are other keys i could use with my current code? other than not being able to freely pick a key it works fine and i would be happy with using things like the numpad or the keys over the arrows, only being limited to just the control keys is a litte hard to work with

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579658/how-to-intercept-all-the-keyboard-events-and-prevent-losing-focus-in-a-winforms) might be helpful.  If you want it in the background, you will need a keyboard hook.  Personally.. I wouldn't suggest it.  Hooking the windows keyboard can make a mess.

Comment: Thx for your answer Senor CMas, i saw similar solutions that hooked the entire keyboard before, its honestly a little much for me thats why i liked the approach i used so far and hoped to be able to change the key somehow

Comment: What you should be doing is using the `RegisterHotKey` API and ALWAYS using key combinations including modifier keys. The idea is to use key combinations that are unlikely to clash with other apps, especially when those apps have focus. If you're trying to basically steal regular keystrokes from foreground apps then your app is acting like like malware, if not actually being malware.

Comment: its definitely not malware :D the reason i did not do that in the first place was that the examples seems to complex for me, but i guess if there is no other way ill have to look into it

Comment: found a possible solution in this video, thx for all the replys and the videos autor!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Er20OPUz3ic